# Can I apply where condition to this query which is category="setting"

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli, woocommerce

```
$metstyl= "SELECT concat(wtt.taxonomy,':' ,GROUP_CONCAT(wt.name separator ',')) as result 
FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` as wtt, `wp_terms` as wt
where (wtt.taxonomy IN ('pa_metal','pa_style') 
AND wtt.term_id = wt.term_id 
AND wtt.count>0)  group by taxonomy";
```

Comment: `WHERE(...... AND catagory='setting')`. Add that. Is there any problem

Comment: this is a wordpress query

Comment: To answer, yes, you can add the condition. Are you facing any problem by adding that condition?

Comment: ya i am show atribute values which is pa_metal,pa_style now i am filter them by catagory which is setting

Comment: @sagarkunjadiya : You can try `where` and also `having` condition. ( Note that you can use `having` if you want to group the records based on that conditions also.

Comment: okk i will try thanks